# Facebook is not detecting Tor activities. Is that a good or bad?

Tags: tor, facebook

I use Tor to visit Facebook because I have to bypass some proxies.

The point is, I can access it without any problem, and my identity on Facebook changes according to the exit node. But when I visit any other site, it promotes a human-authentication method (image selecting or a captcha), and it doesn't work most of the times.

So, where is the problem? Are the other sites providing more identification security than Facebook? Or is Facebook not bothering with Tor and other access attempts that might be from bots?

And from a security perspective, what's the connection between bots and Tor activities?

**Edit:** as mentioned in comments, my evidence to support the assumptions is this:
every site rather than the Facebook is treating me as a bot activity, meaning that I receive a captchas, pictures selection and others to confirm "I'm human". So there is something in Tor activity that is similar to robotic activity, at least from those sites perspective!

And as for suggesting to use Facebook onion hidden service: I'm using Tor to bypass my local proxy, not to hide my id from ISP or other reasons.

Comment: If you want to visit Facebook using Tor, you should use Facebook's Onion Hidden Service address: https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/. I don't think that Facebook isn't detecting Tor users, but rather they detect Tor users and adjusts their security mechanisms to prevent false warnings.

Comment: The first assumption part in your question seems wrong. If you have evidence of the contrary, please expose how you arrived to such a conclusion.

Comment: I agree with @danielAzuelos, there are a lot of assumptions in the question and little evidence to support it.  Do you seriously think a service the size of Facebook is really not aware of the existence of Tor and is not taking appropriate measures ?

Answer (score 1):

to be blunt, most public exit nodes in list format is super easy to obtain. ( i do it for my servers) so its not like they cant.

As for Good or Bad? Both.

Good, for those seeking privacy, or using a not-real profile.

Bad, incase of account hacks, ddos, and other nefarious activities.

Even worse, if the exit nodes are stealing your facebook session cookie (which some most certainly are)

Ya, it kinda makes sense facebook would allow this. 
Your 2 best options are, Allow all Tor(etc) traffic, OR allow NONE.

It makes sense they chose all.

A comment above mentioned they had an onion address, sooo... they know.